# edittext shown with white line in middle when using layout_height="38sp"

Tags: android

I notice when I use android:layout_height="38sp" instead of android:layout_height="wrap_content" in edittext. i get text box with white line in the middle .. any explanation? I need to re size the edittext.

Comment: Same problem for me, no matter which dimensional unit I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using dp or dip for height, not sp - that's for text size.

See this question for an explanation on dimensional units - [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: I tired dp, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Change the backgroundcolor of the edittext
    `android:background="#F0F0F0"`
the edittext is a bit bigger after that, but you can resize it!